# How do I check if a running process is a background process?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I'm currently getting all my computer's running processes with

```
Process[] plist = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Are there any good way to check which processes in the list are running as background processes?

With "background process" I mean a process that isn't visible to the user. I tried to use the WindowHandler to check its position but that didn't quite do it since processes in Windows can run in the background with a WindowHandler set to positive integers.

Comment: What do you regard as a background process? Same as list under Task Manager?

Comment: A process that runs in the "background" without user input and with no window on the screen. So yeah, a process that is currently running but isn't visible.

Comment: "no window on the screen" so, minimized counts?

Comment: nope a minimized window is still running in the foreground of Windows. I guess I could have said "with no window what so ever". :) Daemons and Services are two good examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like checking the window style did the trick:

```
public static bool hasWindowStyle(Process p)
{
    IntPtr hnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
    UInt32 WS_DISABLED = 0x8000000;
    int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    bool visible = false;
    if (hnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        UInt32 style = GetWindowLong(hnd, GWL_STYLE);
        visible = ((style & WS_DISABLED) != WS_DISABLED);
    }
    return visible;
}
```

This returns true if:

- The process doesn't have a Window Style for user input

I've done a little testing and as of now at least this seems to filter out the processes that are running behind the scenes pretty good.

I guess this only work on Windows though.

Comment: Yes, you are [not only allowed but encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own questions!  (I've removed that sentence from your answer.)

Comment: Ah good to know! And thank you :)

Comment: To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use GetWindowLongPtr instead GetWindowLong.