# How to programatically filter apps from processes? | C#

Tags: c#, windows

So I am making an app like Task Manager that shows which apps are running but I can't separate background processes from apps.
my code:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
...
foreach (var proc in processes)
{           
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle))
       {
       }
}
```

However, the problem with this is that background processes have window titles sometimes. Is there a better way to filter out apps? How does task manager filter the apps?

Comment: Task Manager doesn't filter apps.  There is no definition of an "app" as distinct from a process.

Comment: Fine, then how should I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by an "app"? Are you actually asking to enumerate open windows?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813376/how-do-i-check-if-a-running-process-is-a-background-process)? It's not really clear.

Comment: Apps (like in task manager) are the stuff that are running on your desktop, everything else is a background process. Eg. chrome, task manager and excel are apps and nvidida, google drive and anti-malware are processes