# How to get the running application of the windows not all process

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

**Here is code**

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcesses();

Console.WriteLine("System Running Process \n\n");

foreach (Process Proc in process)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Proc.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        IntPtr wHnd = Proc.MainWindowHandle;

        Console.WriteLine("Process Name {0} : status {1}", Proc.ProcessName, !IsIconic(wHnd));
        //ShowWindowAsync(wHnd, SW_RESTORE);


        //SetForegroundWindow(wHnd);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
        //  Console.WriteLine(Proc.ProcessName);
    }
}
```

output of the code   Red Mark application is not using but running in backgroud process and showing

[image]

This is actually i want as desired output

[image]

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813376/how-do-i-check-if-a-running-process-is-a-background-process).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proc.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.ProductName` instead of `Proc.ProcessName`

```
Console.WriteLine("Process Name {0} : status {1}",
                  Proc.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.ProductName, 
                  !IsIconic(wHnd));
```

**Edit:** BTW, if you need the title, you can also use `Proc.MainWindowTitle`

Comment: There is no guarantee that what is present in the file version info matches with what appears in a windows titlebar or Task Manager

Comment: MickyD have you seen the screen shot i have attached with thread..below the code ? thanks in advance i want that desired output and your line of code is giving same result with different names

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find only those processes that have windows, you should check `Process.MainWindowHandle` to ensure that it is not `IntPtr.Zero`:

```
foreach (Process Proc in process.Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero))
{
    ...
```